# PHP/MySQLi -> Says I am connected to database even when there is invalid user

Tags: php, mysqli

I am setting up an install script.  On the first page there are inputs for database name, username, password, etc. and it writes a file.  This works great.  Once they click Save and Continue, it writes the file (i intentionally put the wrong database username and password in to test) and then it redirects them to page 2.  On page 2, this is where problems start occuring.

Like I said..I intentionally put in the wrong username and password.  So, at first, its instantly saying that it cannot establish a connection to the database.  Then, when I try to check the connection, it says there is a connection still.  I am probably trying to check this connection wrong, but not exactly sure.  Below is a preview of what it is saying and a preview of the code that involves this section.

This is what is being displayed.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'kylej_user1568'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/kylej/public_html/database.php on line 6
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'kylej_user1568'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Database Connection Status:
Successfully connected to your database
```

---

This is what the code looks like...

```
include('configuration.php');
if (isset($db_database)) { 
include('database.php');
}

echo '<br /><br /><br />';

echo 'Database Connection Status:<br />';
if ($con) { echo 'Successfully connected to your database'; }
if (!$con) { echo 'We were unsuccessful in connecting to your database, please <a href="#">Go back and reconfigure configuration file</a>.'; }
```

So I guess my main question is:  How do I test the connection to see if there is a valid connection to display whether or not the information entered was successful?

---

EDIT:

here is the db connect file

```
    // Create connection
    $con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

here is the updated check connection code

```
include('configuration.php');
if (isset($db_database)) { 
include('database.php');
}  // if database is set

echo '<br /><br /><br />';

echo 'Database Connection Status:<br />';
if (!$con->connect_error) { echo 'Successfully connected to your database'; }
if ($con->connect_error) { echo 'We were unsuccessful in connecting to your database, please <a href="#">Go back and reconfigure configuration file</a>.'; }
```

and here is the page....

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'kylej_user1568'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/kylej/public_html/WMS/include/database.php on line 6
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'kylej_user1568'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


Database Connection Status:
Successfully connected to your database
```

No matter what I do by the point where I can trying to determine whether or not there is connection to the database, i can't get any kind of errors to report from $con.  Is it possible that the connection doesn't exist by this point?  I'm not sure what is happening to be honest.  I've tried checking for both errors and errno's and nothing.

Comment: Include the code of your configuration.php, change the username and passwords. And your include is missing a '

Comment: the include on my page isn't missing a '..sorry..I had to remove excess link directories and accidentally removed the ' from my post

Comment: and configuration just includes my variables.  Everything is right there because it works on all my other pages when the values are correct.  I know this page works, its something in my check connection code that isn't working right.  I intentionally want it to throw an error, which is why I intentionally put the wrong username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain what is going on without seeing your code that creates `$con`. However, my guess is that your problem comes from a quirk of PHP: `__construct` functions will always return an object. This will be a truthy value, so will pass `if` tests.

In this case, you think `new mysqli(...)` will return `false` if the settings are wrong. It won't. It will return a `mysqli` object that is not connected to the database.

You need to test the [`mysqli::$connect_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) property instead:

```
if (!$con->connect_error) { echo 'Successfully connected to your database'; }
if ($con->connect_error) { echo 'We were unsuccessful in connecting to your database, please <a href="#">Go back and reconfigure configuration file</a>.'; }
```

Comment: This makes sense.  But, I copied and pasted exactly what you put above and it is doing the exact same thing.  I have updated my post with my db connect file.  The variables are being set in configuration.php

Comment: actually, I can't get $con->connect_error; to echo out any kind of error no matter what I try.  Is it possible that it can't find $con by that point in the code?  I can't figure out why..but it seems that there is no $con connection being found.

Comment: @kdjernigan Are you running an older version of PHP, perhaps? `connect_error` had some bugs in some early versions.

Comment: no...it was giving an issue because I was running two mysqli connections and even though they had two different names, I couldn't run those connect_error commands on the 1st connection.  It would only pull the 2nd connection even if I tried calling $con directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the connection error status is this manner:

```
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') '
            . $con->connect_error);
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: check my edited question.  I updated the script to check for errors instead of connection results.  There is obviously an error because it is reporting it at the top; however, the connection status still says connected.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Either check for `mysqli_connect_errno()`

or - better - set mysqli in exception mode. This way you will need no manual error checking at all:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

For the install script you can make it

```
echo 'Database Connection Status:<br />';
try {
    $con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    echo 'Successfully connected to your database'; 
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
   echo 'We were unsuccessful in connecting to your database<br>';
   echo "Database says: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
   echo 'please <a href="#">Go back and reconfigure configuration file</a>.'; 
}
```

this way you will avoid polluting your log files with unnnecessary error messages

Comment: check my edited question. I updated the script to check for errors instead of connection results. There is obviously an error because it is reporting it at the top; however, the connection status still says connected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your code. Most likely you just removed too much "excess code".

Comment: the only code I removed was the full links to the actual database.php and configuration.php file.  They are being pulled in the script..I didn't remove too much code.